# Mixed Integer Linear Program (MILP) question

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization

I am trying to solve an MILP problem. I was wondering if Branch and Cut/Branch and Bound methods find optimal solution or not? Isn't the complexity exponential? Are there heuristic solvers available?
Thanks